# How to parse Ethereum transactions to extract all the details that we see on Etherscan?

Tags: ether, etherscan, ethereumjs

Please consider this transaction: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x800391d2328e82e2cea40fd2cf2600f505baeefeb568e5bd5e75ebdeddcdd888

When I fetch this transaction using web3.eth.getTransaction, I get the following data:

```
{
  accessList: [],
  blockHash: '0x0291205db4a65df246a8b86e75dcad205f58461edab19bcf9f6e76466b52e81d',
  blockNumber: 13470967,
  chainId: '0x1',
  from: '0x3DC378ecdbBFc95bf30448a799c820798f545697',
  gas: 294643,
  gasPrice: '64134232173',
  hash: '0x800391d2328e82e2cea40fd2cf2600f505baeefeb568e5bd5e75ebdeddcdd888',
  input: '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',
  maxFeePerGas: '82354975259',
  maxPriorityFeePerGas: '1500000000',
  nonce: 577,
  r: '0x2b7f1c5c301701b4f5624479ff9be28ead980affcf9632cc648e35fdf36f3db1',
  s: '0x6da124872e0d55e34bba7ff9d82c377bca54035753c11367eee49b9460ec6a1e',
  to: '0x7Be8076f4EA4A4AD08075C2508e481d6C946D12b',
  transactionIndex: 108,
  type: 2,
  v: '0x0',
  value: '1275000000000000000'
}
```

If we look up this transaction on Etherscan we get the following extra details that we don't get from web3.eth.getTransaction:

1. NFT token that was transferred (seller to buyer)
2. Internal transactions (buyer to Opensea and seller)
3. EIP-1559 related details such as the base fee, max fee, and max priority fee
4. Internal values of DOODLES smart contract state variables

My question is that how can I get all this data, I cannot find any API that gives this data, not even EtherScan API.

My understanding is that I might have to run a node and install some callbacks and replay transactions and extract contract state variables out of the EVM. Can someone guide me on where to start?

I am a beginner in this space, any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: PS: I understand that the contract method name and argument values can be decoded and extracted out of the string on the "input" attribute returned by web3.eth.getTransaction. I am mostly concerned about the other values that I listed in the question such as NFT token ID, internal transactions, and contract state variable values.